# How to create a Regex for string with space

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string value like "GX 123-02" or "ML 35-02". The numbers entered after the letters can be any long, but there must be a space after the alphabet followed by the number values. How can I create a regex expression in C# to check if the value is entered in this format?

Comment: [a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]*-[0-9]{2} would match those

Comment: if you're asking how to match a space, you just use a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I got you right, you want exactly two letters followed by at least a space and *number-number*, you can use this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\s+\d+-\d+
```

Note that `\s` matches any white space if you want exactly the space character to be matched at least one time you can simply just replace `\s`  with a space like this:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2} +\d+-\d+
```

Comment: \s+ matches more than just a space. it matches any amount of whitespace

Comment: @juharr of course, it was just a demonstration, but I will update the answer to address this.

Comment: Thanks. This works well. How about if string contains any number of digits after the space like "GB 12-23232-23232"

Comment: Just tried your given regex. It also works for my above scenario. Thanks

Comment: @OseeAliz if you mean number-number-number... then you can use s.t like this: `[A-Z]{2} +(\d+-)+\d+`

Answer (score 1):

**\s is indicates space use following expression it will works** 
[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{5,25}